How to get rid of "Imports array contains unused imports(-998113)"
Ever since I've upgraded my app to the latest version of Angular (18.2.0), I'm getting this warning message in many of the components:

Imports array contains unused imports(-998113)

Now, I understand the meaning of this and why it's showing up like that, and basically it's great that it exists, to let me know (although it doesn't say which import(s) are not used!).
But nevertheless, I don't want it to appear, and without removing unused imports.
Is there a setting or a configuration that I can use to stop getting these warning message?

what code editor are you using? version also

Oh, sorry. Latest version of VS Code

please try upgrading the angular language service plugin, maybe that resolves it

can you add your comment here as an answer to my quesion please?

updated, please check

Is there a script for this? I could never remove every one manually in the new compile warnings.

The warning about unused imports in standalone components was introduced in Angular 19 (you can find more details in the official blog post here: https://blog.angular.dev/meet-angular-v19-7b29dfd05b84).
It seems that you've updated the "Angular Language Service" plugin in VS Code to version 19, but you haven't yet upgraded Angular itself in your package.json.
As a result, you're seeing the warning in VS Code, but when you try to build or serve your app, you encounter the following error: TS-994005: Angular compiler option "extendedDiagnostics.checks" has an unknown check: "unusedStandaloneImports."
To resolve this, you should update your Angular version to v19 in your package.json. This will allow the compiler to recognize the newly added extended diagnostics check for unused standalone imports. Once you've made this update, the TS-994005 error should disappear, and you can also suppress the check in your angularCompilerOptions as needed.

I just upgraded to Angular 19, and without the settings in tsconfig.ts, the warning messages don't appear any more. That is the desired situation for me of course, but is that normal?

Yes, that is expected behavior. There is no warning because the compiler from version 19 now has the ability to check for unusedStandaloneImports.
This check is enabled by default but can be disabled in the tsconfig.json.

You can try upgrading the plugin Angular Language Service to the latest version and probably turn on the auto update checkbox (so that the plugin always has the latest version). If that does not work out try the below suggestion.

This seems to be present in the documentation under:
NG8113 - Unused Standalone Imports

This diagnostic detects cases where the imports array of a @Component contains symbols that aren't used within the template.

Check if there are any imports that you are not using.
@Component({
  imports: [UsedDirective, UnusedPipe]
})
class AwesomeCheckbox {}

If you feel what you have is correct and it seems to bug out, you can temporarily disable it, using tsconfig.json, until it get's fixed in a later release, but you must raise a bug on angular github (if you feel it's a bug).
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "extendedDiagnostics": {
      "checks": {
        "unusedStandaloneImports": "suppress"
      }
    }
  }
}


I just found out that when I try to build the app project (and this setting exists in the tsconfig.json file), I get the following error: TS-994005: Angular compiler option "extendedDiagnostics.checks" has an unknown check: "unusedStandaloneImports". Allowed check names are: ...

@TheCuBeMan So what fixed the error, the first suggestion or the second? have you validated that if there are any unused imports? since the suppress does not work

I am talking about the solution of adding the settings to tsconfig.json. when I do that, the warning messages don't appear any more, but then I get the error in the build process, as described above.

@TheCuBeMan first try doing build with npx run build, if that works please let me know

Right now, I am running this command:
ng build --configuration production --named-chunks=false
Are you suggesting actually the following command:
npx run build --configuration production --named-chunks=false
?

@TheCuBeMan npx ng build --configuration production --named-chunks=false try this
